# Zurb Foundation vertical navbar?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

Hello guys I recently started using Zurb Foundation and now I need vertical navbar like [top bar](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/topbar.html) but vertically. I was playing around [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mDhoq) wit css but with no luck. I searched on google but couldn't find such thing. Is it easy to convert the top-bar to vertical navbar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this **[PEN](http://codepen.io/magnus16/pen/vphFm)**

```
.top-bar{
   height:100%;
   width:150px;
 }
ul.right > li{
  display:block;
  float:none;
  border-bottom:1px solid #444;  
}

ul.right > li:last-child{
  border-bottom:none;
}
.has-dropdown ul.dropdown{
  position:absolute !important;
  left:100% !important;
  top:0px;
  border-left:1px solid #444;
}
```

**Update**:Added right chevron to pen.

Comment: Amazing... thank you very much, now the only thing I need is to rotate the arrow to show to the right :)

Comment: Thats exactly what I wanted, now I will study your extended css to understand how you did it.. thank you again

Comment: One small issue.. if the window is small (Try resizing the output html) there is white line http://oi57.tinypic.com/105a99t.jpg

Comment: That white line is a separator. You can remove it by removing `border-bottom` from `ul.right>li`